# Analyse logs using awk instruction

Tags: awk

i have a log file error.log structured like this:

```
06.06.2019 09:01:33.527 *ERROR* [10.152.55.64 [1559804493473] GET /etc/designs/ca/npc/clientlib-resources/images/commun/slider_0.jpg HTTP/1.1] com.adobe.acs.commons.util.ResourceDataUtil Error creating the String representation for: /content/ca/national/npc/fr/errors/500.html
```

I manage to do it using shell script (see below) --> works fine, but as the file can be heavy i have to use awk to faster treatment.
I would like to do the same by using only awk instruction.

```
function trt_script {

  grep ERROR error.log | while read -r line_full ; do

        line=`echo "$line_full" | awk -F "] : " '{print $1}'`

        elements_lines=($line)
        date=${elements_lines[0]}

        hour=`echo "${elements_lines[1]}" | awk -F "." '{print $1}'`

        type=${elements_lines[2]}

        instruction=`echo "$line" | cut -d'[' -f2-$NF | rev | cut -d']' -f2-$NF | rev`

        instruction_1=`echo $instruction | rev | awk -F " ]" '{print $1}' | rev`

        detail_part1=`echo "$line" | awk -F "] : " '{print $1}' | rev | awk -F " ]" '{print $1}' | rev`
        detail_part2=`echo "$line" | awk -F "] : " '{print $2}'`

        entry_detail_part=`echo "$detail_part1$detail_part2"`

        error_class=`echo "$entry_detail_part" | awk -F " " '{print $1}'`
        error_description=`echo "$entry_detail_part" | cut -d' ' -f2-`

        echo -e "${date};${hour};${type};${instruction};${instruction_1};${error_class};${error_description};" | tee -a result.csv
  done
}
```

what i want in output

```
06.06.2019;09:01:33;*ERROR*;10.152.55.64 [1559804493473] GET /etc/designs/ca/npc/clientlib-resources/images/commun/slider_0.jpg HTTP/1.1;GET /etc/designs/ca/npc/clientlib-resources/images/commun/slider_0.jpg HTTP/1.1;com.adobe.acs.commons.util.ResourceDataUtil;Error creating the String representation for: /content/ca/national/npc/fr/errors/500.html;
```

Comment: given all the code you have, you seem to understand your problem very well. What your asking should be simple to implement in `awk`. Have you worked thur the [Awk Tutorial](http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) ? It will give you all you need to covert this code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

See below for AWK script, which will speed up processing, as it avoid forking large number of awk instances. Using awk 4.1.4/Linux Mint.

Run with: awk -f a.awk error.log > result.csv

```
#! /usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN { OFS=";" }
{
        # Parse
        date=$1
        time=$2
        status=$3
        ip=$4     # [a.b.c.d
        tag=$5    # [nnnnnn]

        action=$6
        url=$7
        protocol=$8
        class=$9
        # Combine everything else into single field
        detail=$10
        for (i=11 ; i <= NF ; i++ ) detail = detail " " $i

        # Print
        f4 = action " " url " " substr(protocol, 1, length(protocol)-1)
        f5 = action " " url " " substr(protocol, 1, length(protocol)-1)
        print date, substr(time, 0, 8), status, substr(ip, 2) " " tag " " f4, f5, class, detail, ""
}
```